# Calculations from radio button inputs in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, radio-button

My expectation is calcualate total price according to user inputted values. Total price is depend on "ToopingPrice" , "Size"  and "Qty". In My code, total price is not calculating. Consider that I am still beginner level in React.

```
  const [quantity, setQuentity] = useState(1)
  const [size, setSize] = useState('medium')
  const [sizePrice, setSizePrice] = useState(product.mediumPrice)
  const [topping, setTopping] = useState('none')
  const [toppingPrice, setToppingPrice] = useState(0)
  const [totPrice, setTotPrice] = useState(product.mediumPrice)
```

Total price calculating function

```
    const calcTotPrice = () => {
    alert.success(product.smallPrice);
    const FtotPrice = (sizePrice + toppingPrice)*quantity
    setTotPrice(FtotPrice)
    alert.success("calcTotal working");
  }
```

This is my radio buttons. I am not sure is it correct way to put onClick method like below.

```
  <div className="selectButton">
   <div className="radio-container">
      <input id="500g" name="size" type="radio" defaultValue="500g"  onClick={size => setSize('small')} onClick={sizePrice => setSizePrice(product.smallPrice)} onClick={calcTotPrice}/>
      <label htmlFor="500g">500 g</label>
      <input defaultChecked id="1Kg" name="size" type="radio" defaultValue="1Kg"  onClick={size => setSize('medium')} onClick={sizePrice => setSizePrice(product.mediumPrice)} onClick={calcTotPrice}/>
      <label htmlFor="1Kg">1 Kg</label>
      <input id="2Kg" name="size" type="radio" defaultValue="2Kg"  onClick={size => setSize('large')} onClick={sizePrice => setSizePrice(product.largelPrice)} onClick={calcTotPrice}/>
      <label htmlFor="2Kg">2 Kg</label>
   </div>
</div>
<div className="selectButton">
   <div className="radio-container2">
      <input defaultChecked id="0" name="topping" type="radio" defaultValue="0"  onClick={topping => setTopping('None')} onClick={toppingPrice => setToppingPrice(0)} onClick={calcTotPrice}/>
      <label htmlFor="0">None</label><br />
      <input id="1" name="topping" type="radio" defaultValue="1"  onClick={topping => setTopping('Fresh Fruit')} onClick={toppingPrice => setToppingPrice(product.freshFruitToppingPrice)} onClick={calcTotPrice}/>
      <label htmlFor="1">Fresh Fruit</label><br />
      <input id="2" name="topping" type="radio" defaultValue="2"  onClick={topping => setTopping('Candies & Cashew Nut')}onClick={toppingPrice => setToppingPrice(product.chocolateCandiesAndCashewNutToppingPrice)} onClick={calcTotPrice} />
      <label htmlFor="2">Candies & Cashew Nut</label><br />
      <input id="3" name="topping" type="radio" defaultValue="3"  onClick={topping => setTopping('Moldable Fondan')} onClick={toppingPrice => setToppingPrice(product.moldableFondanToppingPrice)} onClick={calcTotPrice}/>
      <label htmlFor="3">Moldable Fondan</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to move `onClick` logic into 1 separate function, and call it with different params.

First input will look like this:

```
<input id="1" name="topping" type="radio" defaultValue="1"  onClick={() => recalculate("Fresh Fruit", product.freshFruitToppingPrice)}/>
```

And the function will look like that:

```
const recalculate = (toppingName, toppingPrice) => {
    setTopping(toppingName);
    setToppingPrice(toppingPrice);
    calcTotPrice();
}
```

Thats the first step, then simply we can debug this code.

Comment: Your answer helped me to figure out solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting `NaN`? because it seems to me that your problem is providing the wrong type of data for the calculation.
are `sizePrice`, `toppingPrice`, and `quantity` numbers?

I think your `quantity` might be a string or something.

Also, why are you having this many `onClicks` on a single input? :D

Comment: I got Nan because of wrong data type. I converted them to number format by using `Number(quantity )`. Thank you for that advice

Comment: no problems. glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Your ‘calcTotPrice’ handler should be an **effect hook**. Try

```js
useEffect( () => {
     alert.success(product.smallPrice);
    const FtotPrice = (sizePrice + toppingPrice)*quantity
    setTotPrice(FtotPrice)
    alert.success("calcTotal working");
},[product, sizePrice, quantity, setTotPrice]);
```

Comment: By adding `alert.success(product.smallPrice);
    const FtotPrice = (sizePrice + toppingPrice)*quantity
    setTotPrice(FtotPrice)
    alert.success("calcTotal working");` in to useEffect keep reload browser whenever click on radio button

Comment: Well, I thought that is what you want!?